# Fields in Report server not showing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence, reportserver

I have done some reports in B.I.Ds and everything works as it should
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBLvt.jpg
However when I deploy them to our report server, random fields contain no values
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTvPG.jpg in this case the 'claimstatusprogkey'

Does any one have any clue as to whats going on with this? I'm not sure where the problem could be or really how to start to diagnose the issue

Comment: When you preview in Business Intelligence Developer, are you using the same DataSet as when you deploy to your report server?  If not, then I would suggest verifying that the data source on the report server actually contains the data that you expect.

Comment: Second @DrewCo. In fact, we can't really help you (except by guessing), you need to debug this yourself first. Run the dataset query seperately, start a blank report with the same query if you have to, etc. Tell us about anything you find, be as specific as possible with your problem description.

Comment: That's why I had the images. I run the sproc and all the data I expect to see is there. I ran the profiler and ran that in the SSMS and I received all the data as expected. I can hard code values in the questionable fields, that shows up when I deploy it

Comment: Do you have an expression at the 'claimstatusprogkey' field? When you run the query with the user which you provided in the data source that attached to the report on the report server you getting the value?

Comment: The images don't help too much, try to help us reproduce the issue, create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Place yourself in our shoes, we only see symptoms: an empty textbox. The reason could be anything. (If all else fails, there's always [binary search debugging](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/50552/how-to-effectively-do-manual-debugging/181223#181223)).

Comment: @silagy I do. That's what I'm not understanding, the query returns all necessary data but Report viewer isn't displaying all of the data when I deploy it. In preview mode, all the data is diplayed

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your Data Source definition differs between BIDS and Report Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the dataset using the same sproc and voila. I did change the sproc and refreshed the fields in the Dataset and for whatever reasons it wasn't updating. Now I'm getting what I expecting. Thank you